# Terraform CIDR block variable validation

Tags: validation, variables, terraform

**Terraform variable validation for CIDR, looking alternative for regex**

Below is the tested code in Terraform version 13.0
is there any alternative way to achieve same thing with not using regex?

cidr block - start 172.28.0.0.0/16

```
    variable "vpc_cidr" {
      description = "Kubernetes cluster CIDR notation for vpc."
      validation {
        condition     = can(regex("^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}($|/(16))$", var.pod_cidr))
        error_message = "Vpc_cidr value must be greater than 172.0.0.0/16."
      }
    }
```

how to validate CIDR block 172.28.x.x/16 with cidrsubnet function?
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrsubnet.html

validation condition - if IP range is outof 172.28.x.x/16 then validation will be failed

Comment: Please can you edit your question explain what would be considered valid and what would be considered invalid? Your current validation (with a few tweaks to fix bugs) seems to match a lot of things that are not valid CIDRs plus prefix less CIDRs (would normally be considered a `/32`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a direct way to achieve what you want with the functions in today's Terraform, but I think we can break the check into two conditions that, taken together, lead to the same effect:

1. The zeroth address in the subnet must be `172.28.0.0`.
2. The netmask of the range must be `255.255.0.0`.

We can test these two rules using two expressions:

1. `cidrhost(var.vpc_cidr, 0) == "172.28.0.0"`
2. `cidrnetmask(var.vpc_cidr) == "255.255.0.0"`

Both of these functions can fail if given something that isn't valid CIDR block syntax at all, and `cidrnetmask` will additionally fail if given an IPv6 address, so we can add [`try`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html) guards to both of them to turn that error into a false result as `condition` expects:

1. `try(cidrhost(var.vpc_cidr, 0), null) == "172.28.0.0"`
2. `try(cidrnetmask(var.vpc_cidr), null) == "255.255.0.0"`

The `try` function will return the result of the first expression that doesn't produce a dynamic error, so in the above examples an invalid input to the `cidrhost` or `cidrnetmask` function will cause an expression like `null == "172.28.0.0"`, which will always be false and thus the condition will still not be met.

Finally, we can combine these together using the `&&` operator to get the complete `condition` expression:

```
  condition = (
    try(cidrhost(var.vpc_cidr, 0), null) == "172.28.0.0" &&
    try(cidrnetmask(var.vpc_cidr), null) == "255.255.0.0"
  )
```

Comment: Looking at this again with fresh eyes, I realize that I probably misunderstood the question, because the expression I wrote above is effectively the same as `var.vpc_cidr == "172.28.0.0/16"` aside from it potentially allowing non-canonical forms like `172.028.000.000/16`. However, I see it was accepted so perhaps it was a good enough starting point for an answer; I just wanted to add this note in case someone else sees this in future and wonders the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the solution from https://dev.to/drewmullen/terraform-variable-validation-with-samples-1ank

```
variable "string_like_valid_ipv4_cidr" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"

  validation {
    condition     = can(cidrhost(var.string_like_valid_ipv4_cidr, 32))
    error_message = "Must be valid IPv4 CIDR."
  }
}
```

Also note, as commented there, that the condition requires a modification to work for /32 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You have one `0` to many and it should be greater then 172.0.0.0/16. For example:

```
172.1.0.0/16
```

not:

```
172.0.0.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hack, but still:

```
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  validation {
    condition = cidrsubnet("${var.pod_cidr}/16", 0, 0) == "172.28.0.0/16"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heavily based on [MartinAntkins Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66645123/361842) this code allows you to ensure that a CIDR is not only a correctly formatted value; but that the prefix is valid for the size; i.e. `10.0.0.1/16` is invalid, as the first IP in the range would be `10.0.0.0`, which is before the prefix itself.

```
variable "demoIpv4Cidr" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.1/16" # try "10.0.0.0/16" for a valid value 
                          # or "10.0.0.x/16" for an invalidly formatted cidr

  validation {
    condition     = (
      can(cidrhost(var.demoIpv4Cidr, 0)) &&
      try(cidrhost(var.demoIpv4Cidr, 0), null) == split("/", var.demoIpv4Cidr)[0]
    )
    # the above could be simplified to:
    # condition = cidrhost(var.demoIpv4Cidr, 0) == split("/", var.demoIpv4Cidr)[0]
    # ...though that would throw "Error in function call" instead of "Invalid 
    # value for variable" were an invalid cidr (10.0.0.x/16) were used.
  
    error_message = "InvalidCIDRNotation: The CIDR is not correctly formatted, or the address prefix is invalid for the CIDR's size"
    # InvalidCIDRNotation is an existing error code; so may be helpful if anyone googles it.
  }
}
```